# The code doesn't run while I run it on my computer but it works on the tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("https://www.google.com/") 
# print(result.status_code)
# print (result.headers)
src = result.content
#print(src)
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
 links = soup.find_all("a")
 print (links)
 print ("\n")
```

The code doesn't run while I run it on my computer but it works on the tutorial. The code doesn't run from the print (links) I tried installing lxml but it didn't run.

Here is the error message:

```
python -u C:\Users\HP\Desktop\scrapping\p1.py
] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\scrapping\p1.py",
line 13, in print (links) File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 72-77: character maps to [Finished in 1.271s]
```

Comment: What is "doesn't run"? And are the indents in your code the same as in here?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: runs well for me ...

Comment: Can you add an error message?

Comment: @JoséRodrigues  how did it run ?  It doesn't work in my laptop

Comment: @Jeremad Command: python -u C:\Users\HP\Desktop\scrapping\p1.py] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\scrapping\p1.py", line 13, in print (links) File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 72-77: character maps to [Finished in 1.271s]

Comment: Add this line: `# coding: utf-8` at beginning of your file (don't miss a `#` character)

Comment: @HanxiFu it shows indentation error

Comment: Well, you should know that in Python you should use indents of 4 spaces, and 3 last lines in your post have  wrong indent.

Comment: @MichaelO. can you post the corrected code

Comment: Delete spaces in beginning of lines

Comment: @MichaelO. The traceback clearly shows it has nothing to do with the extra spaces ... that is just a bad paste of code

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that `links` contains unicode characters that cannot be translated to the default codepage that Windows uses in a command prompt/console.

Try the following to change both the codepage and the way python encodes the io streams (assuming you are using `python-3.2` or later).

```
> chcp 65001
> set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
> run-your-program-here
```

At that point they may agree about how to handle such characters